# When dependance exists between two quantities?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, scientific-method

Suppose we have two quanitities X and Y and we try to find out if a third quantity Z depends on them.

**1st case** Changing the X holding Y constant doesn't change Z.

**2nd case** Changing the Y holding X constant changes Z.

**3nd case** Changing both X and Y (simultaneously) changes Z.

Can from the first two cases conclude that Z does not depend on X? What if we change both X and Y simultaneously and now Z changes differently than the 2nd change? For example if Y were doubled in the 2nd case then Z doubled but in the 3rd case doubling Y quadrupled Z (no matter what change X undergoes). Could we say in that case that Z does not depend on X?

Comment: It is not clear if X and Y are independent variables or if they are the only variables Z depends on. This question is more suitable for [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Conifold Thanks for the answer. Can I transfer the question in  Math SE or Cross Validated?

Comment: It will be faster if you delete it here and post there.